# Historic Topo Sources

Tags: data, topography

Middle of a project, wondering if there is a better historic topo source than TheNationalMap for finding historical maps for an area.
Coring some lakes, would be nice to know that they've been there for at least a few hundred years.

Comment: If it is open data that you are seeking then researching/asking at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange may be advised.  Where have you looked besides [The National Map](https://nationalmap.gov/)?

Comment: What area do you need?

Comment: Thumb of Michigan.

Comment: For open data you could research/ask at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OldMapsoline](http://www.oldmapsonline.org/en/Rocky_Mountains#bbox=-134.53857449999998,35.165946713738506,-103.90885392016514,50.60414455359603&q=&date_from=0&date_to=9999&scale_from=&scale_to=) is the best source I know for an old map.
This map are mostly from the eighteenth century.
In the home page you can insert a location into the search box 
One other option is move around the map and see what pop out [image]
In the left bar you have a list of maps and their descriptions.
When you click on a map you it will open a new window that allowed you to download the map.

Comment: Thanks! Tried to upvote but not enough reputation.